# Encryption of password in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, password-encryption

I am creating a table of user account and I want to hide the password when I execute the query of SELECT from user account. can anyone help me with this, how can I hide the actual password inserted into the table.

thanks
Regards
Waqar

Comment: I googled "oracle encrypt password function" and I got a ton of interesting hits. Did you you try anything ?

Comment: Generally speaking, don't store the actual password in a table. Make a one way hash (e.g. using SHA256) and store the hash value. If you want to hide the hash column, then use Virtual Private Database, or use views instead of direct access to the table to mask the content.

Comment: I did 
none of them seems to work on Oracle Apex

Comment: what does "not seem to work" mean ? Error message ? Hard to help you with the little information you provided. What did you try (provide reproducible case if you want help) where did you get stuck ?

Comment: You can't really "hide" any of the data in the database. If you're storing it, *someone* is going to be able to view it. If nothing else, you're not going to be able to hide it from the SYS user. Which is why you should never store passwords in cleartext. Never. Ever. All those cases where some business gets compromised and their users' data leaked to the internet? That's how this happens.

Answer (score 0):

use this type function to encrypt your user password before save.

```
 FUNCTION get_hash (p_username IN VARCHAR2, p_password IN VARCHAR2)
      RETURN VARCHAR2
   AS
      l_salt   VARCHAR2 (3000) := 'test';
   BEGIN
      RETURN DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH (
                UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW (
                   UPPER (p_username) || l_salt || p_password),
                DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH_SH1);
   END;
```

Comment: Note: this is not encryption